# i want to export a single table from the database witout using phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

i have only ftp credentials in which i am using this script

```
$r="mysqldump $dbuser $dbpass $dbname wp_posts > table1.sql";

system($r);
```

but unfortunatly m getting a blank result in table1.sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally i got the solution, here is my code:

```
<?php
$username = "abc";
$password = "xyz";
$hostname = "domain.com";
$database = "test_db";
$username =escapeshellcmd($username);
$password =escapeshellcmd($password);
$hostname =escapeshellcmd($hostname);
$database =escapeshellcmd($database);
$backupFile='url'.date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").$database.'.sql.tgz';

 $command = "mysqldump -u$username -p$password -h$hostname $database wp_posts > $backupFile";
system($command, $result);
echo $result;
?>
```

thnx for your support, really appreciate it.

Comment: Any reason why you're using the tgz file extension? The output doesn't seem to be a tgz file to me, just a regular text .sql file.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the option switches to your command, see the [mysqldump manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html), like this

```
$r="mysqldump -u $dbuser -p $dbpass $dbname wp_posts > table1.sql";
```

Comment: in the above script is there need any host variable?

Comment: @jassi9911 I don't believe you need it, it will default to localhost: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_host But you will need to specify it if you can't connect via localhost

Answer (score 0):

if the user has the permissions try this:

```
mysqldump -u$dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname wp_posts > table1.sql
```

to specify the parameters (which is the user and which is the password)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's

```
mysqldump -u $dbuser -p $dbpass $dbname wp_posts
```

Apache user needs to have the permission to write table1.sql and also execute mysqldump command. If on shared hosting, this is doubtful.